# Access field in a column in a Lotus Notes view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

In Lotus Notes, I have view which has got a column say PolicyNum. Requirement is while double clicking on the document to open, which will open the attachment in the form in the view, it has to be validated against a computed field say SecureDoc which contains either Yes or No.
For client version this is easy as in the queryopen in the form it is validated and exited if the condition doesn't meet with proper messagebox.

But for the web version the column is appeared as a link and the messagebox has to appeared as alertbox in JS. In the PolicyNum column I have tried to use @GetField("SecureDoc") which will get the value of the field for that particular document.

### Column Formula:

furl:="javascript:alert('Document not available');return false";
OpenDisp:="[" + PolicyNumber + "]";
secDoc:=@GetField("SecureDoc");

### @If(att = "" ; OpenDoc ;secDoc="Yes";OpenDisp;OpenAttach)

Here OpenDoc and OpenAttach are different string which will open the document and attachment respectively depending on the att, which checks for the attachment.@GetField("SecureDoc") return "". So if I write @If(att = "" ; OpenDoc ;secDoc="";OpenDisp;OpenAttach) it is showing the alert box and is working fine.
So the requirement is to get the handle of the field value for the particular doc which is to be clicked on web and check for the condition.
Also webqueryopen is not working..
Note: On opening the document it is opening the attachment in the form and not the form itself.
Column Value :

```
view := "0";
att := @AttachmentNames;
WebName := @WebDbName ;
url := "'/" + WebName + "/" + view + "/" + @Text(@DocumentUniqueID) + "/$File/" + att + "?OpenElement'";
url := "window.open(" + url + ");" ;
url := @Implode(url; ";");
url := "javascript:" + url + " return false;\" href=\"javascript:void(0);";
furl:="javascript:alert('Document not available');return false";
OpenAttach := "[<TABLE><TR><TD NOWRAP><a  target=_blank onClick=\"" + url + "\">" + PolicyNumber + "</a></TD></TR></TABLE>]";
OpenDoc := "[<TABLE><TR><TD NOWRAP><a href=\"/" + WebName + "/" + @Subset(@ViewTitle; -1) + "/" + @Text(@DocumentUniqueID)  + "?OpenDocument\">" + PolicyNumber + "</a></TD></TR></TABLE>]";
OpenDisp:="[<TABLE><TR><TD NOWRAP><a  target=_blank onClick=\"" + furl + "\">" + PolicyNumber + "</a></TD></TR></TABLE>]";
secDoc:=@GetField("prevSecDoc");
@If(att = "" ; OpenDoc ;secDoc="Yes";OpenDisp;OpenAttach)
```

I have tried with both @If(att = "" ; OpenDoc ;secDoc="Yes";OpenDisp;OpenAttach) and @If(att = "" ; OpenDoc ;prevSecDoc="Yes";OpenDisp;OpenAttach) but it is not getting the value as "Yes". Though when I open the document through URL giving the docid it ha the value as "Yes"

Answer (score 1):

Quick back to basics : a *document* is a record in a database, a *form* is, well, a form, which determines how data are input by the user and controls display.

Allow me to rephrase your question. If the document contains a field named "SecureDoc", and if said field holds the value "NO", then a click on the link must not open the document and present the user with a JavaScript alert.

One could question why display the document in the view in the first place, and then why have a link with no other effect than telling it has no effect.
OK, not my place to question the requirements.

My suggestion would be that the content of the column displayed for web access be a computed hyperlink :

```
href := @If( SecureDoc = "NO";
            "javascript:alert('nope')";
            "normal url for opening the doc"
           );
"<a href=" + href +">" + "the title of the doc or whatever" + "</a>"
```

Comment: Requirement is, user should be able to see the document but cannot open it,here on opening it will pen the attachment in the form,and will give alert of not authorized.
Also @If(SecureDoc="No") cannot be accessed until and unless I open the document. It is being written in column value.

Comment: Look for the column value in the question